# List wireless networks on Mac with external WiFi adapter

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, mac, airport

I know I can use the `airport` command on a Mac to list nearby wireless networks, but this only seems to work for the built-in WiFi card. How can I do this if I'm using an external, USB WiFi adapter?

So far, I know:

1. I can connect using the adapter without a problem, so I know it works.
2. I can see the list of networks in the `Wireless Network Utility` application, so I know a scan is possible.
3. On Linux, I would use something like `iwlist` but that's not available for the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Your only hope is to use the software that came with your adapter (or other software available from the vendor of your adapter). Apple never opened the OS X Wi-Fi driver APIs to third-party driver/adapter developers, so developers of aftermarket Wi-Fi adapters for Macs have to write all their own software.

Comment: Ack, really? Total bummer. It's a Realtek from Adafruit (http://www.adafruit.com/products/1030) – any chance you've had experience with those, or can recommend one that would be easy to hack?